# How can I assert an audio play in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have a scenario where there are multiple audio files (more than 10000) and I need to find a solution to check that whether all audios are playing well on browsers.. Can someone please suggest how can I do it in selenium or any workaround for this.

Comment: Please provide specifics around the implementation.  Are you using any specific player or relying on HTML5 capabilities?

Comment: I'm using HTML5

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437228/html5-check-if-audio-is-playing
You can take the concept from the answer and implement it in the language you are using.  Please note, this only covers the part where the browser starts playing an audio file.

Answer (score 1):

As @ramnath said, it would be better if you provide more information about the audio player.
In the worst case, where you won't be able to assert automatically the audio, you can automate part of the testing implementing something like the Cucumber's method ask.

See more information in this link: http://technicaldebt.com/manual-cucumber-tests/

Although it won't be as fast as a computer, this "semi-automated" test can be done with better reliability.

Comment: Thanks Joao, It doesn't completely solve my purpose but helped me to achieve the same.